# Git: How does checking out affect the repository?

Tags: git

I'm not at all experienced with programming, and I'm just starting to learn Git. I don't understand how `git checkout` works.

According to [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/viewing-old-commits):

> Checking out an old commit is a read-only operation. It’s impossible to harm your repository while viewing an old revision. The “current” state of your project remains untouched in the master branch.

Yet the paragraph below, they state this:

> On the other hand, checking out an old file does affect the current state of your repository.

Seems to me to be completely contradictory. Could someone please explain this to me in layman's terms?

Answer (score 4):

The second sentence could better be written as:

> checking out an old file does affect the current state of your *workspace*

If you think of the repository as the history of all versions of files throughout the project's history, the workspace is a snapshot of files in some state.

`checkout` moves content from the repository into the workspace. It only *reads* from the repository, but it *writes* to the workspace. Therefore it cannot change the repo, but it can change your workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Git's documentation definitely leaves something to be desired.

One of the answers above hits a key point, which is that if you ask `git checkout` to get a *specific file* from a specific revision, this has a bigger effect than you might expect.

#### Background

What you need to know here is that there are *three* things-of-interest when it comes to checking out files:

- the repository itself
- your work-tree
- the thing git calls "the index" or "the staging area"

There's a fourth item, the current branch, that `git checkout` also affects, but this part is obvious at first.  Eventually it becomes a bit less clear, in the usual git fashion. :-)  I'll get to that in a bit.

When it comes to using `git checkout` to "go back in time" to an earlier commit, it's fairly clear that this should affect your work tree.  There's no way to look at the earlier version of `README.txt` unless git actually extracts the earlier version of `README.txt`.  Thus, of course `git checkout` affects the work-tree.

The repository itself, however—the collection of every version of every file that has ever been committed, plus all the commits themselves—is in fact unaffected, so it's reasonable to say that the *repository* is read-only here.  (In fact, operations that change stuff, adding new commits, mostly just *add* to the repository.  It's very hard to get git to forget anything once that thing is `git commit`-ed.  Even operations that *appear* to remove things, such as deleting commits during an interactive rebase, really only *add* things.  But that's for another time.)

#### Using `git checkout`

Now, this is where it gets a bit squirrelly: `git checkout` is, in my opinion, actually about two to five fairly different (though related) commands, all squished into one `git checkout` command.  The exact number depends on how clearly you want to separate these (I'd say they should at least be split into two, myself):

1. Check out a particular branch, e.g., `git checkout master` or `git checkout feature`.
2. Check out an old commit, so that you're not on a branch at all: `git checkout afe3ca9` for instance, or `git checkout v1.2` where `v1.2` is a tag.
3. Extract, into the work-tree, a file (or perhaps many files) taken from the current index (I'll get to this in a bit): `git checkout -- fromindex.txt`, for instance.  The `--` is only needed if the name of the file might resemble a valid revision-ID, but it's a good idea to include it always, lest you accidentally use something you *think* is safe, but it turns out to map to a valid revision-ID.
4. Extract, into the work-tree, a file (or perhaps many files) from an old commit, but without moving from the *current* commit: `git checkout master~20 README.txt` for instance.
5. Re-create a merge conflict, or resolve a merge conflict by picking a particular version: `git checkout -m recreate.py` or `git checkout HEAD file.c`.  (Note that this last one looks the same as for command #4.  The key difference here is that command #4 applies only when you're in the middle of a conflicted merge, and that's due to the way merges use the index.  We'll have more on this in a moment.)

Each of these commands has a different effect.

A branch checkout puts you "on" that branch, removing and/or replacing any work-tree files that are needed to get there.  This kind of checkout is careful not to clobber any modifications you've made in your work-tree, and it will give you an error if you'd lose some work (at which point you can save that work first, then use the force flag, for instance).

A history checkout is very similar to a branch checkout.  If you `git checkout v1.2`, to see what was in the commit that was tagged as version 1.2, git does the same safety-checks as for changing branches.  The key difference is that if all is well, git gets you the commit tagged `v1.2` and you're no longer on *any* branch.  You have what git calls a "detached HEAD".  (You can "detach your head" even when checking out a branch, by adding `--detach`.  There's rarely much reason to do that, and there are other ways to do it, so the `--detach` flag is actually completely unnecessary, but that's another issue entirely.)

Both of these kinds of `git checkout` move you from one commit (and/or branch) to another, different commit.  They update the work-tree, and also change git's idea of your current branch/commit.

I mentioned earlier that "current branch" gets a bit hazy when you look closely.  This is because of that "detached HEAD" thing.  In order to record your current branch, git writes the branch name into a file, `.git/HEAD`.  You can peek at this file with a file-viewer or your editor (be careful not to remove it though, as if it's gone, git will stop believing you have a repository!).  Normally this file contains `ref: refs/heads/master` or `ref: refs/heads/branch`, and that's *how* git knows what branch you're on.  But the file can also contain a raw SHA-1, one of those big ugly 40-character IDs that are the "true names" of commits.  This is when you have a "detached HEAD", and in this case, that SHA-1 is your current commit.  (When you're on a branch, the current commit ID is kept in the branch's file: `.git/refs/heads/master` for instance, but sometimes these refs are "packed" to save space and time.)

Now let's get back to checkout command types #3 through #5.  These *do not* check to see if you'll clobber something in your work-tree, because they also *do not* change your current commit ID, nor affect your current branch.  Instead, they overwrite your work-tree with the contents of the selected file(s) from the selected commit—or, for re-creating a merge, with the result of re-attempting the merge you're in the middle of.  But they do one more, very important, thing: they *write to the index*.  (Or, you might want to think of this as writing *through* the index, to the work-tree.)

Why does this matter?

#### Why the index matters

Git uses the index to build the *next* commit, the one you have not made yet, but will when you run `git commit`.  That's why it's also called the "staging area": it's where you arrange the files, and then once everything is arranged the way you want, you simply run `git commit` to snapshot the staging area into the repository, making a new commit.

What this means is that if you're on branch `master`, for instance, and your work-tree and index are both clean, but then you decide to look at an older version of `README.txt`:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout master~20 README.txt
```

then git has not only updated your work-tree, it's *also* modified your current index, so that if you do a new `git commit`, you'll put back the old `README.txt` file.

You can switch the index version back easily:

```
$ git checkout master README.txt
```

but you need to remember to do that.  (You can also do this with `git reset`, but note that `git reset`, like `git checkout`, is several commands all squished into one.)

#### A brief word on merges

I mentioned that merges use the index specially.  If you're in the middle of a conflicted merge, git keeps three<sup>1</sup> versions of each conflicted file in the index, which are generally called "merge-base", "ours", and "theirs", but are also counted: 1, 2, and 3.  To "resolve" the merge, you tell git to replace these three with "version 0".  When you use `git add` to add a resolved merge, that's what you're doing; but you can also resolve the merge with `git checkout`, which writes to version-number-zero, so that versions 1-3 are resolved away.

When you run `git checkout -m`, this variant of checkout removes version 0 and re-creates versions 1-3.  You don't need to know all of this normally, but it's there for recovery from mistakes in the middle of a merge.

---

<sup>1</sup>Because merges can run into file-deleted or file-created operations, it's actually *up to* three versions.  If the file was not present in the merge-base but is present in both changes-to-merge, you'll have a conflict with no entry in the "merge-base" slot, in the index.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first paragraph explains

```
git checkout <some commit>
```

and the second paragraph explains

```
git checkout <some file>
```

They have different semantics, in particular the first one is read-only, while the second one does change the state of your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are in your master branch, which is ur perfect current state.

```
git checkout master
```

Imagine, you just want to get into specific state or see how things are when you made certain commit, imagine **the name of commit is 97b4b6c.** If you made 97b4b6c commit previously, git provides an option where you can get into that state and checkout the repository.

> Remember `git checkout ~97b4b6c` is going into 97b4b6c commit state.
>   By going into this state, your current state (master) will no be
>   harmed. You can get back to your current state (master) anytime. This
>   is like, you can switch between A(master) and B (97b4b6c) states, this
>   switching will not affect either A or B.

```
   .             .
A (master)    B (97b4b6c)

git checkout ~97b4b6c #commit name
```

If you’re only interested in a single file, you can also use git checkout to fetch an old version of it. For example, if you only wanted to see the hello.py file from the old commit, you could use the following command:

```
git checkout commit hello.py
```

In the same way, If you want to see the hello.py in master state and hello.py in 97b4b6c commit.

```
           .             .
hello.py-A (master)    hello.py-B (97b4b6c)

git checkout 97b4b6c hello.py
```

will show you hello.py file in 97b46c commit state. In the same way you can see his same file in master state also by doing this:

```
git checkout master hello.py
```

Remember, unlike checking out a commit, this does affect the current state of your project. The old file revision will show up as a “Change to be committed,” giving you the opportunity to revert back to the previous version of the file. If you decide you don’t want to keep the old version, you can check out the most recent version with the following.

**Summary:**

```
git check <commit>
```

will take you to specific commit state, and

```
git checkout <some file>
```

> However, the vital difference between git checkout  and git
>   checkout  is, `git checkout <commit>` will not affect the
>   current state of your project but `git checkout <some file>` will
>   definitely affects your current state of project

will also take you to its specific file's older version

So, git checkout is a command which is basically taking you to some state. Either it is doing that by commit name or file name.